# best server for google speed test results?

Tags: server, web, pagespeed, web-development-server, google-pagespeed

We are trying to improve our google speed test results and I was told there are some mysterious "better quality" servers that will improve results. Currently using dreamhost. Any tips on servers that increase website speed? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, having a dedicated server with high internet speeds is pretty important. If multiple services are running on the same server (such as multiple users using the same server), it will bring the performance speed down. Also, below are some other factors to account for:

- Minimize HTTP Requests
- Reduce server response time
- Enable compression
- Enable browser caching
- Minify Resources
- Optimize images
- Optimize CSS Delivery
- Prioritize above-the-fold content
- Reduce the number of plugins you use on your site
- Reduce redirects

For more detailed suggestions, visit: https://blog.crazyegg.com/2013/12/11/speed-up-your-website/

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to Google Speed Test, its many things, i recommend you use a cache as memcached or redis, use minify static files, try to use your styles on the HTML on  tag